# Obtaining real solutions to cubic equations using cubic formula

Tags: analysis, functions, polynomials

I have used the cubic formula to find the exact value of sin(pi/7) and the expression for sin(pi/7) contains imaginary numbers which cannot be removed. 
My question is, how can there be imaginary terms of the decimal approximation is real? It just seems weird to me that you cannot get rid of the imaginary numbers in the exact value, but you put it in on a calculator and you get a purely real number result.

Comment: They imaginary parts will eventually cancel out

Comment: You might be even more shocked to learn that $\sin(z) = \frac{e^{iz}-e^{-iz}}{2i}$ for all $z\in\Bbb C$ (and in particular $z\in \Bbb R$)

Comment: Yeah I know the exponential definitions of the trig functions. Quite amazing really - isn't maths great?

Answer (score 1):

When you use a calculator or a computer, the value of any trigonometric function is computed using series.

The simplest would be, for your case, $$\sin(\frac \pi 7)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{(2k+1)!}\Big(\frac \pi 7\Big)^{2k+1}$$ Computing the partial sums, this would lead to the following results
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 k & S_k \\
 0 & 0.44879895051282760549 \\
 1 & 0.43373273249518920891 \\
 2 & 0.43388446475197967392 \\
 3 & 0.43388373708562913631 \\
 4 & 0.43388373912128078478 \\
 5 & 0.43388373911755331234 \\
 6 & 0.43388373911755812509 \\
 7 & 0.43388373911755812047 \\
 8 & 0.43388373911755812048
\end{array}
\right)$$

Calculations are in fact made faster using $$\sin(\frac \pi 7)=\sin(\frac \pi 6-\frac \pi {42})=\frac{1}{2} \cos \left(\frac{\pi }{42}\right)-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}  \sin
   \left(\frac{\pi }{42}\right)$$ and using series for a much smaller angle.

Solving the cubic $$64 y^3 - 112 y^2 + 56 y - 7=0$$ you effectively get the monster $$y=\frac{7}{12}-\frac{7^{2/3} \left(1+i \sqrt{3}\right)}{12\ 2^{2/3} \sqrt[3]{-1+3 i
   \sqrt{3}}}-\frac{1}{24} \left(1-i \sqrt{3}\right) \sqrt[3]{\frac{7}{2} \left(-1+3
   i \sqrt{3}\right)}$$ but using the trigonometric method for solving cubic equations, this reduces to $$y=\frac{1}{12} \left(7-2 \sqrt{7} \cos \left(\frac{1}{3} \tan ^{-1}\left(3
   \sqrt{3}\right)\right)\right)$$ which then leads to  $$\sin(\frac \pi 7)=\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\frac{1}{3} \left(7-2 \sqrt{7} \cos \left(\frac{1}{3} \tan
   ^{-1}\left(3 \sqrt{3}\right)\right)\right)}$$